# gvim case-insensitive not working on Solaris 10

Tags: gvim

Ok, so totally frustrated here.  Running gvim (VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled May 27 2008 23:56:31).  Have set up my .vimrc to have case insensitive search (set ic).  ( No difference using .gvimrc either).

When vi'ing a file, over 50% of the time, it will only reflect case-sensitive searches.  Sometimes closing current vi session, and re-opening will enable the ic option, but not always.  Also trying to set it via the Files -> Global Settings -> Ignore Case does not help.

Current .vimrc contents:

```
set number
set bg=light
set ic
set smartcase
set autoindent
set mouse=a
syntax on
set ruler
set viminfo='10,\"100,:20,%,n~/.viminfo
```

Comment: Your `.vimrc` also contains `set smartcase`. Maybe you're trying to search for a pattern, which contains uppercase letters?

Comment: No, just looking for plain old text, nothing special.  As an example, searching for C++'s "main()" function, with Main will not locate it.  It's crazy...

Comment: Okay, so it will work if and only if after opening the file, I use GVIM's Edit -> Global Settings -> Toggle Vi Compatible setting (but not if I do this myself within vi using :set cp!).

Comment: It's not crazy, it's what `'smartcase'` option does. If at least one of pattern letters is an uppercase letter the case is not ignored (see `:help 'smartcase'`). And when you toggle vi compatibility the `'smartcase'` option is reset as stated in the documentation.

Comment: I could understand that, however, I'd since commented out (") smartcase, and issue still exists....

Comment: Did you check its value in some buffer with `:set smartcase?`? Maybe it's set by some plugin. If it's set you can use `:verbose set smartcase?` to find out where it was set (you may need to run Vim with `-V` flag for that command to work).